# How to validate - and + sign in input box when type is number in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try to validate an input box (), it is accepting a `+` and `-` sign. I want to validate both, or that input box should not accept any symbol including `+` and `-` sign both.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply using pure JS method like following:

```
var n = Number('-1')    // n = -1
var n = Number('--1')   // n is NaN
var n = Number('+1')    // n = 1
var n = Number('-+1')   // n is NaN
var n = +'-1'           // n = -1
var n = +'--1'          // n is NaN
var n = +'+1'           // n = 1
var n = +'-+1'          // n is NaN
var valid = !Number.isNaN(n)
```

if `valid` is `true` -> `n` is a number, else -> `n` is not a number